# conditional regex case match for email in python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a list of email addresses:

```
emails = ['email@google.com', 'email@happytown.aau.edu', 'fox.trot@nickle.com.uk']
```

I was using:

```
re.findall(r'\w+@\w+\.\w+', emails)
```

But I'm not sure how to account for the extended TLD's. How would I make this a conditional match so that we match all email addresses regardless of the ending?

Comment: There are better ways to do it but to answer your specific question, set your pattern to `r"[\w.]+@[\w.]+\.[\w]+"`

Comment: @jk622 worked like a charm. thank you